# Does the Microsoft Graph API metadata confirm the OData Protocol specification?

Tags: odata, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

### Microsoft Graph API metadata

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata?detailed=true

ll.6791 - 6795

```
<Action Name="createSession" IsBound="true">
  <Parameter Name="this" Type="microsoft.graph.workbook"/>
  <Parameter Name="persistChanges" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false"/>
  <ReturnType Type="microsoft.graph.workbookSessionInfo"/>
</Action>
```

### 11.5.1 Binding an Operation to a Resource

http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc453752308

> Actions and Functions MAY be bound to an entity type, primitive type, complex type, or a collection. The first parameter of a bound operation is the *binding parameter*.

---

"createSession" Action does not have "bindingParameter". 
Is this a correct specification for the Microsoft Graph API metadata?
How can I report this to the Microsoft Graph team if this is an incorrect specification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you quoted, the spec says:

> The first parameter of a bound operation is the binding parameter.

So in this case the parameter named "this" is the binding parameter.  It is not necessary for the parameter to be named "bindingParameter".

Comment: Thanks a lot! If you were a maintainer of msgraph-sdk-ruby, I want you to know that msgraph-sdk-ruby can not parse the binding parameter named "this".

Comment: @jinroq Thanks for that info.  I will add that as an issue to the repo.  As soon as we have a Ruby dev on our team we will get that sorted.